# Find the partial derivatives ∂f/∂x and ∂f/∂y for f(r,θ)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

Given $f(r, θ) = r^2\sinθ$, $x = r \cos θ$ and $y = r \sin θ$, how to compute $\frac{∂f}{∂x}$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂y}?$ This should be possible using the chain rule, but I'm not sure how to best calculate the separate partial derivatives, nor can I find a good resource on it.

Comment: You should start writing $g(x,y)=f(r,\theta)$ to avoid confusion. Then express $x,y$ in polar coordinates and apply the chain rule.

Comment: Another way would be to notice that $$f = r^2\cdot \sin(\theta)=r\cdot y=y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}.$$
In matrix form,
$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} &\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} &\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\end{pmatrix} \! \!\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \end{pmatrix}.$$ Thus
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} &\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\\ \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} &\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} \end{pmatrix}.$$ For the final result, replace $r \cos \theta$ by $x$ and $r \sin \theta$ by $y.$

Answer (score 1):

The 'trick' stated by @HappyDay seems to be the best choice:
$$
f = r^2 \sin \theta = ry
$$
Thus
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}y
=\frac{x}{r}y
$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
=\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}y + r
=\frac{y}{r}y + r
$$

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the coordinate differentials
$$\eqalign{
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\v#1{\begin{Bmatrix}#1\end{Bmatrix}}
\def\t{\theta} \def\c{\cos\t\,} \def\s{\sin\t\,}
\def\cc{\cos^2\!\t\,} \def\ss{\sin^2\!\t\,}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
x &= r\c &\qiq dx = \c\,dr -\s\,(r\,d\t) \\
y &= r\s &\qiq dy = \s\,dr +\c\,(r\,d\t) \\
}$$

$$\eqalign{
\v{dx\\dy} &= \m{\c&-\s \\ +\s&\c}\cdot\v{dr\\r\,d\t} \\
\\
\v{dr\\r\,d\t} &= \m{\c&+\s \\ -\s&\c}\cdot\v{dx\\dy} \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
dr &= \c\,dx + \s\,dy \\
r\,d\t &= \c\,dy -\s\,dx\quad \\
}$$

Then differentiate the function
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\a#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\b#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\a{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BLR#1{\b{\LR{#1}}}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
f &= r^2\s \\
df &= \s\LR{2r\,dr} + r^2\LR{\c d\t} \\
 &= 2r\s\,\a{dr} + r\c\,\b{r\,d\t} \\
 &= 2r\s\,\CLR{\c\,dx + \s\,dy} + r\c\,\BLR{\c\,dy -\s\,dx} \\
 &= \LR{r\c\s}\,dx \;+\; \LR{r+r\ss}\,dy \\
\grad{f}{x} &= r\c\s, \quad \grad{f}{y} = r+r\ss \\
}$$